# Entity Framework returning null children, underlying SQL is fine

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm currently having strange issues with null child values using Entity Framework connecting to a Pervasive database. I'm pretty new EF so my terminology may be wrong.

I have two classes, we'll call them Parent and Child.  This is how they're set up:

```
public class Parent
{        
    public int ParentUK { get; set; }
    public int ParentName { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

With a mapping file

```
public class Parent_Map : SchemaNameEntityTypeConfiguration<Parent>
{
    public Parent_Map(string schemaName)
        : base(schemaName)
    {
        ToTable("Parent");
        HasKey(p => p.ParentUK);

        Property(p => p.ParentUK)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        Property(p => p.ParentName)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(p => p.Status)
            .IsRequired();

        HasMany(p => p.Children)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentUK);
    }
}
```

And the Child class

```
public class Child
{
    public int ParentUK { get; set; }        
    public int Sequence { get; set; }
    public int ChildName { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
public class Child_Map : SchemaNameEntityTypeConfiguration<Child>
{
    public Child_Map(string schemaName)
        : base(schemaName)
    {
        ToTable("Child");

        HasKey(t => t.ParentUK);
        HasKey(t => t.Sequence);

        Property(t => t.ParentUK)
             .IsRequired();

        Property(t => t.Sequence)
             .IsRequired();

        Property(t => t.ChildName)
             .IsRequired();

     }
}
```

When I run the following query, I expect to get a list of 2 Parents with 3 Children each.

```
var result = context.Parents
     .Include(p => p.Children)
     .Where(p => p.ParentUK < 3);


foreach (var thing in result)
{
     if (thing.Children != null)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(thing.ParentName+ "  has some children " + thing.Children.Count);
     } 
     else
     {
          Console.WriteLine(thing.ParentName+ "  has NO children ");
     }
}
```

I've verified that the underlying SQL includes the join between the two tables and returns 6 rows.

The problem that I'm struggling with is that the first result does contain a list of children but the second result's list is null.  If I run the query going after individual IDs, everything works properly so I don't know if my mapping is the problem.

If I run the query with more results, it'll be something like

```
P1  has some children 3
P2  has NO children
P3  has NO children
P4  has NO children
P5  has some children 3
P6  has NO children
P7  has NO children
P8  has NO children
```

If I run the query with lazy loading, I'll get similar results but instead P7 will have children and P5 won't.

This is a generic example but it should illustrate my problems.  I'm really not sure why EF is struggling to populate the lists.  It doesn't throw any exceptions but I'm not sure if it silently logs somewhere.

Comment: `.Where(to => p.ParentUK < 3);` is that a typo? Shouldn't it be `to.ParentUK`?

Comment: Yeah, typo copying real code to example code.  I'll fix it up.

Comment: Your question bounces around to much when you get to the results. What is the result of running your example? What do you mean by run the query with more results?

Comment: @GertArnold The problem is that the Child's primary key is a composite key of the Parent's UK and a sequence number.  Not my design but I have to live with it.  It's just odd that it works if I go after individual rows, like "Where(p => p.ParentUK = 1)" or something.

Comment: @Andomar Entity Framework is just fine. It's code-first Entity Framework that's a pain. DB-first is incredibly straightforward for small or medium sized databases.

Comment: @Guvante I'm sorry for bouncing around.  It was hard to explain. If I run the query with a larger result set than 2 parents, I get seemingly random results that work and the rest that don't.

Comment: @JoeEnos: After half a year of EF, you always get freakingly difficult problems, like fixing a 50.000 line EDMX file in a text editor.  The real fun starts after two years when you try to upgrade to a new EF version.  I just think to myself, how on earth did we let simple data access degenerate into multi-day debug session complexity?

Comment: @Andomar I guess it depends on what you're doing with it. I've used database-first EF for simple data access (CRUD with simple LINQ joins) for years on decent sized databases, and never had to even look at my EDMX - as long as your primary and foreign keys are right in the database, you won't have a single problem. You can delete and recreate your EDMX at any time with zero impact. You probably shouldn't upgrade EF though, since each new version makes breaking changes. And if you're doing funky stuff, like custom entities or manual relationships, then yeah, you're asking for trouble.

Comment: @Andomar: Dapper seems an awful lot like return to the raw SQL days that lead to the creation of tools like Entity Framework. Sure you don't have to manually handle the result set, but there aren't even compile time syntax checks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to replace...

```
HasKey(t => t.ParentUK);
HasKey(t => t.Sequence);
```

...by...

```
HasKey(t => new { t.ParentUK, t.Sequence });
```

...which is the correct way to define a composite key. In your original mapping `HasKey(t => t.Sequence)` overwrites `HasKey(t => t.ParentUK)` so that EF only considers the `Sequence` as the key.

Comment: Thank you so very much!  This was definitely the reason.  I saw the double HasKey in some composite-key tutorial and never gave it a second thought.  

Thanks again!